# How do i remove the square brackets [ ] that are printed with the number in my string

Tags: python, mysql, apache, phpmyadmin

I am a industrial mechanization (engineering) student from the netherlands and started learning python scripting  for this project so i am still pretty green

I am making a program that takes information from a omron-plc and then sends it true a raspberry pi to a mysql data base for storage

I have the connection working from the omron-plc to the raspberry i can see the data it sends.
I also have the connection from the raspberry to the mysql working.

But the data from the plc comes with  [<---on the outside--->] but mysql wont allows those square brackets to be used so how can i remove them ?

it seems that it was embedded in an array--

If you need more info to help i will gladly supply it

Gr
Daniel V

```
# Echo client program
import socket
import re
#--------------------------------------------------------------------
import MySQLdb
#--------------------------------------------------------------------
#HOST = '192.168.200.50'    # The remote host
#PORT = 9600              # The same port as used by the server
#s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
#s.connect((HOST, PORT))

finsErrorsStrings = {
0x0000000:None,
0x0000001:'The header is not FINS (ASCII code)',
0x0000002:'The data length is too long.',
0x0000003:'The command is not supported.',
0x0000020:'All connections are in use.',
0x0000021:'The specified node is already connected.',
0x0000022:'Attempt to access a protected node from an unspecified IP',
0x0000023:'The client FINS node address is out of range.',
0x0000024:'The same FINS node address is being used by the client and server.',
0x0000025:'All the node addresses available for allocation have been used.',
}

def int2str4(k):
    return chr((k>>24) & 0xff) + chr((k>>16) & 0xff) + chr((k>>8) & 0xff) + chr((k>>0)   & 0xff)

def int2str3(k):
    return chr((k>>16) & 0xff) + chr((k>>8) & 0xff) + chr((k>>0) & 0xff)

def int2str2(k):
    return chr((k>>8) & 0xff) + chr((k>>0) & 0xff)

def binstr2int(s):
    n = 0
    for i in range(0, len(s)):
        n += ord(s[i]) * ( 1<<(8*( len(s)-i-1)))
    return n

def str2intlist(s):
    return [ord(c) for c in s]

def intlist2str(l):
  return ''.join([chr(e) for e in l])

def wordlist2str( wl):
    if wl[0] != 0xff:
        print '-- Neplatna'
        return ''
    cs  = ''
    for d in wl[1:]:
        n1 = ((d>>8) & 0xFF)
        n2 = (d & 0xFF)
        if n1==0:
            break
        if n2==0:
            cs += chr( n1)
            break
        cs += chr( n1) + chr( n2)
    return cs

class FinsTCPframe():
    def __init__(self, cmdData='',  rawFinsCmd = None,  cmdFlags = None,  DA1=None,      SA1=None,  MRC=None,  SRC=None,  command=0x02, errorCode=0x00, serverAdr = 0,  clientAdr =     0, rawTcpFrame=None ):
        self.FINScommandFlags=           ['ICF','RSV','GCT','DNA','DA1','DA2','SNA','SA1','SA2','SID','MRC','SRC','data']
        if rawTcpFrame:
            self.fromRaw = True
            self.rawTcpFrame = rawTcpFrame
        else:
            self.fromRaw = False
            if (MRC or SRC or cmdData) :
                #have some command data
                commandFlags  = [
                    0x80, # ICF
                    0x00, # RSV 'RSV':0
                    0x02, #'GCT':0x02
                    0x00, #'DNA':0
                    serverAdr, #'DA1':0
                    0x00, #'DA2':0
                    0x00, #'SNA':0
                    0x00, #'SA1':0
                    clientAdr, #'SA2':0
                    0x00,  #'SID':0
                    MRC, #'MRC':0
                    SRC, #'SRC':0
                ]
                if cmdFlags:
                    for k in cmdFlags.keys() :
                        commandFlags[ self.FINScommandFlags.index( k)] = cmdFlags[k]
                commandFrame = intlist2str(commandFlags) + cmdData
            else:
                #frame have TCPheader only or raw Fins Command Packet Provided
                if rawFinsCmd :
                    commandFrame = rawFinsCmd
                else:
                    commandFrame = ''
            self.rawTcpFrame ='FINS'
            self.rawTcpFrame += int2str4( 8 + len( commandFrame))    #frame length
            self.rawTcpFrame += int2str4( command)
            self.rawTcpFrame += int2str4( errorCode)
            self.rawTcpFrame += commandFrame

    def makeFrame(self):
        self.finsFrame = 'FINS'
        self.frameLength = 8 + len( self.finsCmdFrame)
        self.finsFrame += int2str4( self.frameLength)
        self.finsFrame += int2str4( self.finsCommand)
        self.finsFrame += int2str4( self.finsErrorCode)
        self.finsFrame += self.finsCmdFrame
        return self.finsFrame
    @property
    def raw(self):
        return self.rawTcpFrame
    @property
    def disassembled(self):
        asm = {
               'header'   : binstr2int( self.rawTcpFrame[ 0: 4] ),
               'length'   : binstr2int( self.rawTcpFrame[ 4: 8] ),
               'command' : binstr2int( self.rawTcpFrame[ 8:12] ),
               'errCode' : binstr2int( self.rawTcpFrame[12:16] ),
        }
        if( asm['command'] == 2) :
            asm[ 'ICF'] = binstr2int( self.rawTcpFrame[16])
            asm[ 'RSV'] = binstr2int( self.rawTcpFrame[17])
            asm[ 'GCT'] = binstr2int( self.rawTcpFrame[18])
            asm[ 'DNA'] = binstr2int( self.rawTcpFrame[19])
            asm[ 'DA1'] = binstr2int( self.rawTcpFrame[20])
            asm[ 'DA2'] = binstr2int( self.rawTcpFrame[21])
            asm[ 'SNA'] = binstr2int( self.rawTcpFrame[22])
            asm[ 'SA1'] = binstr2int( self.rawTcpFrame[23])
            asm[ 'SA2'] = binstr2int( self.rawTcpFrame[24])
            asm[ 'SID'] = binstr2int( self.rawTcpFrame[25])
            asm[ 'MRC'] = binstr2int( self.rawTcpFrame[26])
            asm[ 'SRC'] = binstr2int( self.rawTcpFrame[27])
            if self.fromRaw :
                #decode from response
                asm[ 'MRES'] = binstr2int( self.rawTcpFrame[28])
                asm[ 'SRES'] = binstr2int( self.rawTcpFrame[29])
                asm['response'] = self.rawTcpFrame[30:]
            else :
                asm['cmd'] = self.rawTcpFrame[28:]
        return asm
    @property
    def error(self):
        #return None if ok, else errorstring as string
        try:
            ec = binstr2int( self.rawTcpFrame[12:16])
            if ec == 0:
                ec = None
        except:
            ec = 'Error code not found'%self.finsErrorCode
        return ec
    @property
    def command(self):
        return binstr2int( self.rawTcpFrame[ 8:12])
    @property
    def commandResponse(self ):
        return  self.rawTcpFrame[30:]
    @property
    def finsData(self):
        """Return raw data after FINS TCP header"""
        return  self.rawTcpFrame[16:]
    def __str__(self):
        asm = self.disassembled
        str = ''.join([ "{0}:{1} ".format(k, asm[k], ) for k in asm.keys()])
        return str

class OmronPlcFinsTcp():
    def __init__(self, host, port):
        self.port = port
        self.host = host
        self.sock = None
        self.open = False
        self.clientNode = 0
        self.serverNode = 0
        self.sid=0x04
    @property
    def _nextSid(self):
        self.sid = (self.sid + 1 ) & 0xff
        return self.sid
    def openn(self):
        if self.open :
            #close if already open
            self.sock.close()
            self.open = False
        #open socket
        self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.sock.connect((self.host, self.port))
        self.sock.settimeout( 1)
        #start establish fins communication
        print 'FINS cmd: request address'
        c1 = FinsTCPframe ( command = 0,  rawFinsCmd = int2str4(0))
        print "Sending: " + str( c1)
        self._send( c1.raw)
        r1raw = self._recieve()
        r1 = FinsTCPframe( rawTcpFrame = r1raw )
        print "Recieved: " + str( r1)
        if r1.error:
            print 'Error in adress assign response: %s' % r1.error
            try :
                print ' - this mean>%s' % finsErrorsStrings[r1.error]
            except :
                pass
            return False
        #set client and server address against response
        if r1.command != 1 :
            print 'Error bad response for  adress assign command: ' % r1.command
            return False
        self.clientNode = binstr2int( r1.finsData[0:4])
    self.serverNode = binstr2int( r1.finsData[4:8])
    print 'FINS address client:{0},server{1}'.format(self.clientNode, self.serverNode, )
    #Get PLC type as test dummmy command
    return self.doFinsCommand( MRC=0x05, SRC=0x01, cmdData = '\x00')[0:20]
def doFinsCommand(self, MRC,  SRC,  cmdData):
    #cmdData='',  rawFinsCmd = None,  cmdFlags = None,  DA1=None,  SA1=None,  MRC=None,  SRC=None,  command=0x02, errorCode=0x00, serverAdr = 0,  clientAdr = 0, rawTcpFrame=None ):
    c = FinsTCPframe(MRC=MRC, SRC=SRC, cmdData = cmdData,  serverAdr=self.serverNode, clientAdr=self.clientNode,  cmdFlags = {'SID':self._nextSid} )
    #print "Sending: " + str( c)
    self._send(c.raw)
    r_raw = self._recieve()
    r = FinsTCPframe( rawTcpFrame = r_raw )
    #print "Recieved: " + str( r)
    #print " disasm>" + str(r.disassembled)
    #TODO: check error and status..
    return r.commandResponse
def close(self):
    self.sock.close()
    self.open = False
def _send(self,  raw):
    self.sock.send( raw)
    #print ' Send:' + repr(raw)
def _recieve(self):
    pr = self.sock.recv(8)
    length = binstr2int( pr[4:8])
    r = pr + self.sock.recv( length)
    #print ' Recv:' + repr(r)
    return r


class OmronPLC():
    def __init__(self):
        self.conType = None
        self.plcType = None
        self.MEMCODES = {
           #'MemType':(word,bit)
           'C':(0x30, 0xB0),
           'W':(0x31, 0xB1),
           'H':(0x32, 0xB2),
           'A':(0x33, 0xB3),
           'D':(0x02, 0x82),
        }

    def openFins(self, address,  port=9600):
        self.conType = 'FINS'
        self.conn = OmronPlcFinsTcp( address,  port)
        self.plcType = self.conn.openn()
        if (self.plcType) :
            print 'Open successfull to ',  self.plcType,  'at ', address
        else :
            raise Exception('Failed to open PLC')
    def doRawFinsCommand(self,  **kvarg):
        self.conn.doFinsCommand( kvarg)
    def close(self):
        if self.conType == 'FINS':
            self.conn.close()
    def readMemC(self, mem,  length ):
        memSpec= re.search('(.)([0-9]*):?([0-9]*)',mem).groups()
        ( memCodeB,  memCodeW) = self.MEMCODES[ memSpec[0]]
        #construct mem specification form
        if memSpec[2] :
            #BIT specs
            memAdr = chr( memCodeB) + int2str2( int(memSpec[1])) + chr(                 int(memSpec[2]))
    else:
        #Word Spec
        memAdr = chr( memCodeW) + int2str2( int(memSpec[1])) + chr( 0)
    rawres = self.conn.doFinsCommand( MRC=0x01, SRC=0x01,
                                cmdData = memAdr + int2str2(length*2))
    if memSpec[2] :
        #bit spec
        res = list( rawres)
    else:
        res = [ ord( rawres[i]) * 256 + ord( rawres[ i+1]) for i in range(0,  len(rawres)/2, 2)]
    return res

def writeMemC(self, mem, wdata ):
    memSpec= re.search('(.)([0-9]*):?([0-9]*)',mem).groups()
    ( memCodeB,  memCodeW) = self.MEMCODES[ memSpec[0]]
    #construct mem specification form
    if memSpec[2] :
        #BIT specs
        raise Exception("Bit memory write : Not Implemented")
    else:
        #Word Spec
        memAdr = chr( memCodeW) + int2str2( int(memSpec[1])) + chr( 0)
        rawdata = ''
        for d in wdata:
            rawdata += int2str2(d)
    rawres = self.conn.doFinsCommand( MRC=0x01, SRC=0x02,
                                cmdData = memAdr + int2str2(len(rawdata)/2) + rawdata )
    return rawres
```

## --------------------------------------------------------------

## plc data

```
import time

def main( ):
    plc = OmronPLC( )
    plc.openFins('11.0.0.4', 9600)
    print plc.readMemC('D2010', 1)
    print plc.readMemC('D2010', 2)
    print plc.readMemC('D2010', 3)
    print plc.readMemC('D2010', 4)
    print plc.readMemC('D2010', 5)
    print plc.readMemC('D2010', 6)
    print plc.readMemC('D2010', 7)
    print plc.readMemC('D2010', 8)
    print plc.readMemC('D2010', 9)
    print plc.readMemC('D2010', 10)
```

## --------------------------------------------------------------

## data converting scrip here (emty atm)

## --------------------------------------------------------------

## main script ender

```
    lastt = ''
    plc.close()
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

## -----------------------------------------------------------

## data to mysql uploading

```
db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", user="rendisk", passwd="raspberry",
                            db="rendisk_flexwaste")

sql = "INSERT INTO plc_log(data) VALUES ('%s')" % (plcput)
try:
    db.cursor.execute(sql)
    db.commit()
except:
    db.rollback()
cursor.close()
db.close ()
```

## -----------------------------------------------------------

this is what that scrip prints atm

FINS cmd: request address
Sending: header:1179209299 length:12 command:0 errCode:0 
Recieved: header:1179209299 length:16 command:1 errCode:0 
FINS address client:251,server4
Open successfull to  CP1L-EL20DT1-D3]        at 11.0.0.4

[3]

[3, 8]

[3, 8, 0]

[3, 8, 0, 0]

[3, 8, 0, 0, 0]

[3, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0]

[3, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

[3, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

[3, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

[3, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/combie.py", line 354, in 
    cursor.close()
NameError: name 'cursor' is not defined

there is only two problems atm that cursor error and that it wont transfer the date it collects in plc data to the mysql

Comment: I am not sure how phpmyadmin and apache have anything to do with this question; and code is certainly needed.

Comment: sorry for the code delay

Comment: Antti Haapala, i am using apache and phpmyadmin in combination with Mysql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like it is still an array!

`myNumber[0]`

should cover it :)

Comment: The question says the data comes as a string with bracket characters, not an array.

Comment: i will try to post a part of the script so you can see

Comment: Oh i see.. SO something like this: `myString.replace(/[\[\]']+/g,'')`

Comment: it turn out your first coment about the nummber [0] was spot on thank

Comment: AHa! Let me change it back :)

Answer (score 0):

If the answer ALWAYS contains those brackets in the same position, you could use:

```
yourString[1:-1]
```

which will return the substring from the second character to the character before the last one.

Comment: ok i am going to try it now and thanks for your fast response

Comment: i will try to post a part of the script so you can see

Answer (score 0):

```
d=['hai','hai1','hai2']
d=str(d)
# this part is remove the '[' from the string
for ch in ['[',']',"'",","]:
  if ch in d:
    d=d.replace(ch," ")

print d
```

result:

```
  hai    hai1    hai2
```